# MySql query result to have nested arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I just want my query to return a result looking like this:

```
array(
   [k1] => data1
   [k2] => data2
   [items] => array(
       [item1] => array(
               .... data inside
       )
       [item2] => array(
               .... data inside
       )
   )
)
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT o.*
     , ot.tracking_number
     , p.id payId
     , p.customer_id payCustId
     , p.name payName
     , p.status payStatus
     , p.charge payTotalCharge
     , op.*
  FROM orders o
  JOIN payments o 
    ON p.id = o.payment_id 
  LEFT
  JOIN orders_tracking ot 
    ON ot.order_id = o.id 
  JOIN orderdetails od
    ON od.order_id = o.id
  JOIN orderproducts op
    ON op.orderdetail_id = od.id
 WHERE p.customer_id = $customer_id;
```

What is wrong with my query that it won't return the way I wanted it to?
Thanks.

Comment: None of the PHP MySQL APIs will return a nested array like that. You need to construct it yourself in the loop that processes the results.

Comment: Which framework you are using ?

Comment: @NaveedRamzan codeigniter

Comment: No amount of sql joining will create an array as a result - an sql join just creates flat rows of results. The nesting will need to be created in nested PHP loops making multiple SQL calls.

Comment: @Barmar Okay man, I'll try it.

Comment: I am sure if you follow proper naming convention for models then it will provide you nested array of related tables.

Comment: The closest thing to this is PDO's `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`, which will create an associative array keyed on a particular column.

Comment: @Barmar: how would I do that in my query?

Comment: You wouldn't, since that's not what you want your results to look like.

Comment: If you use that, the results it returns look like `array(key1=>array(row1, row2, row3), key2=>array(row4, row5), key3=>array(row6, row7, row8, row9), ...)`

Comment: @entreprenerds No. You only need one call.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks man, I solved it already. I really constructed it the way I wanted it to look like although it spent additional processes just to look it like that. Thanks man.